# Set rule in web.config for Express in iisnode

Tags: node.js, iis-8, iisnode

The examples provided in [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) only deal with a single file (such as hello.js) and they set a rule in the `web.config` file like this:

```
<!-- indicates that the hello.js file is a node.js application 
to be handled by the iisnode module -->

<handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" path="hello.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>

<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="myapp">
      <match url="myapp/*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="hello.js" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

When dealing with a normal express application we should use `bin/www` as our default start.

I'm currently just replacing `hello.js` for `bin/www`, is that the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

To run an Express application in IISNode using the rewrite rules, just specify your main file for your Express app and you'll be good to go. No need to assign `bin/www`.

Comment: But in bin/www file there is the code to create server and listen to the port. Infact the app.js (in the root) is called from www file. How can i configure it?